# Implementing AIDL interface

Tags: android

In my application I have implemented an aidl interface by the name IRouteRecording.aidl which is in the package com.google.android.apps.myroute.services.IRouteRecording.
Why am I getting an error while trying to import com.google.android.apps.myroute.services.IRouteRecording from a different package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a whole lot of detail to go by here, but I'm going to assume you're in Eclipse and have a different project for your second package. Have you ensured that project containing your AIDL interface is included in the second project's build path?